# Why does my code only work when running the first function but the second function gives me a referenced before assignment variable?

Tags: python, function

I've tried changing the name of the variable thinkig that was the issue but that didn't fix it. I'm trying to calculate the additive persistence and multiplicative persistence and the additive and multiplicative roots of a number entered into the get_numbers function. For the additive_calculator and multiplicative_calculator functions whichever one I call first works, but the second one gives me an error at the print statement saying that the value of of the root, which I called total and total2 in this case, gives me a referenced before assignment error. I have no idea what to do to fix this error.`enter code here

```
from functools import reduce
def get_numbers():
    num = (int(input("Please enter an integer(negative integer to quit):")))
    nums = [int(a) for a in str(num)]
    return(nums)

nums = get_numbers()
print(nums)


def additive_calculator(nums):
    print("Additive loop")
    counter = 0
    while len(nums) > 1:
        for num in nums:
            len(nums)
            total = 0
            total = sum(nums)
            list.clear(nums)
            nums = [int(a) for a in str(total)]
            print("sum:", total)
            print(len(nums))
        counter = counter + 1
    print("Additive persistence", counter,",", "Additive Root:", total)
print("DONE")
            



def multiplicative_calculator(nums):
    print("multiplicative loop")
    counter = 0
    while len(nums) > 1:
        for num in nums:
            len(nums)
            total2 = 0
            total2 = reduce(lambda x, y: x*y,(nums))
            list.clear(nums)
            nums = [int(a) for a in str(total2)]
            print("sum:", total2)
            print(len(nums))
        counter = counter + 1
    print("multiplicative persistence", counter,",", "multiplicative Root:", total2)
print("DONE")


multiplicative_calculator(nums)            
additive_calculator(nums)
```

Comment: If only one number is entered, `while len(nums) > 1` never executes and therefore `total` (or `total2)` is never assigned.

Comment: what if I entered a four digit number like 1234? what would cause the error then? or would that be considered 1 number? nums = [int(a) for a in str(nums)] converts the number to a string, slices it into it's individual digits, and then turns them back into integers in the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign to a variable anywhere in a function, that variable is considered a local variable (unless declared global or nonlocal). It doesn't matter if you actually do the assignment when the function runs; it suffices that there is some statement in the function that assigns to it.

For example, in the function below, you assign to the variable `a` only if the argument `b` is true, but `a` is still a local variable if you don't assign to it (when `b` is false).

```py
def f(b):
    if b:
        a = "foo"
    return a


f(True)   # -> "foo"
f(False)  # error
```

It's the same with loops. If you assign to a variable in the body of a loop, or the variable in a `for` loop, that variable is a local variable even if you don't execute the body of the loop. If you execute the body, the variable is assigned to, and it is safe to read it, but if you do not execute the body, the variable isn't initialised, and it is an error to read it.

```py
def f(x):
    for a in x:
        pass
    return a


f([1, 2, 3])  # -> 3
f([])         # error
```

In your code, if `nums` is empty, `total2` is never assigned to. It is still a local variable because there is an assignment to it in the code--it doesn't matter that the statement is never executed--but it is an error to read the variable if you haven't assigned to it.

The fix is simple: make sure you initialise `total2` regardless of whether you enter the loop body or not.

```py
def multiplicative_calculator(nums):
    print("multiplicative loop")
    counter = 0
    total2 = 0  # move initialisation of total2 here
    while len(nums) > 1:
        # same code as before...
    # when you get here, total2 is initialised whether you
    # entered the loop or not.
    print("multiplicative persistence", counter,
          ",", "multiplicative Root:", total2)
```

Comment: do I need to declare a second instance of the original nums list? because now my answer is always zero, even when it shouldn't be.

Comment: My change only affects the case when nums is empty. Then the function now returns zero. If it also returns zero when it shouldn’t, then it is the original code not handling that case correctly. Declaring new variables is unlikely to fix anything. That is just giving new names to existing things

Comment: It is a bit of a mystery to me what the loop is supposed to do, but it looks wrong many places. You change nums while you are iterating over it. That is never a good idea. You multiply the digits of a number, which will give you zero if there are any zero digits. The inner initialisation of total2 doesn’t do anything, because you overwrite it right after, and the same is the case for clearing nums. I can’t help figure out what is wrong because i have no idea what it is supposed to do